# when to malloc and when not to -- c programming

Tags: c, malloc

I have few issues regarding when to use `malloc` or in this case `strdup`.
Below is the small function which I have stolen from internet.
I am trying to understand the code but stuck with few issues.
 1. the code has assigned value to `psrc` and `pdest`. example

```
char* psrc = dups;  
char* pdest = s;
```

Doubt: don't we need to use `malloc` to allocate space for psrc and pdest.? If not then why.

1. `pdest [0] = '\0';`
   The above line allocates termination character at the starting of `pdest` string. then previously why we   have assigned `pdest`  to `s` . example `char* pdest = s;`?

Any help or criticism will be helpful to me.
Thanks and regards,
Sam

```
 char* deldupchars (char* s)    
 {      
   char* dups = strdup (s);      
   if (dups)     
   {      
    char* psrc = dups;      
    char* pdest = s;      
    char ch;      

    pdest [0] = '\0';      
    while ((ch = *psrc++) != '\0')    
    {            
     if (! strchr (pdest, ch))    
     {           
       *pdest++ = ch;           
     }             
    }       
    pdest [0] = '\0';      
    free (dups);       
   }      
   return s;       
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char* psrc = dups;
```

No need to allocate here since `dups` was allocated by `strdup`.

```
char* pdest = s;
```

No need to allocate here since `s` was allocated by the caller.

```
pdest[0] = '\0';
```

This writes into the contents of the string. The assignment `pdest = s` assigns pointers but not contents.

Comment: Sorry guys , I am changing my solution.

Comment: I got halfway.
to my 1st doubt I got better understanding about why we are not using malloc.

but I still got confusion on 2nd part

The code is making pdest a null string and then adding values into it as far as its not duplicate.
but then why it is adding pdest[0] = '\0'; after the while loop. This to my understanding is again making string pointed by pdest and s to nulll.

Comment: During the loop `pdest` is incremented and the `'\0'` assignment after the loop is to the end of the string.

Comment: ohh, I got poor concept and was thinking that pointer pdest still points to starting address of string s. while in reality we are moving pointer.

Comment: Thanks a lot david for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

We don't have to allocate memory for for dups because the char* psrc = dups statement does not copy what dups points to, just where it points. This means the allocation done in strdup is enough for both pointers

Answer (score 0):

`strdup()` `malloc()`s the memory for the string, which is why you can store through the pointer that `strdup()` returns. But you have to `free()` that memory, which you correctly do.

From the `strdup()` man page:

> The  `strdup()`  function  returns  a  pointer to a new string which
>   is a    duplicate of the string s.  Memory for the new string is
>   obtained  with    `malloc(3)`, and can be freed with `free(3)`.

Answer (score 0):

strdup will do the malloc inside it and return the allocated memory (that's why you need to call free(dups) in the end of the function).

pdest/psrc are just a pointers (i.e.: just references the memory that was previously allocated from 's', and later is used to walk in that allocated memory). I think the main confusion is that pointers are just that: they point to an address in memory -- so, you can have many pointers to the same memory address and you can use that pointer to walk -- in the previously malloc'ed memory).

See: http://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man3/strdup.3.asp

Answer (score 0):

1) What you get in *psrc* and *pdest* is no more than another pointer to the character string. This doesn't mean you have 2 character strings, but two pointers to the same string. String is not duplicated. You don't need to allocate *psrc* and *pdest* because the compiler is already allocating memory for those variables when you declare them (just like you don't need to allocate memory for *int a*, for example). They're just 32 bits unsigned integers (for 32-bit systems, that is).

2) pdest is used to not modify original s value, since pdest is modified inside the while loop. Again, the string is NOT duplicated, so actually pdest is modifying the string pointed by s.

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't have value assignment there, but pointers assignment. This means that `psrc` points at the same memory location as `dups`. If you want to copy content of that memory location then you need to allocate memory and then copy. (malloc + memcpy)
2. `pdest [0] = '\0';` - no allocation here. This just places null-terminator at the beginning of array it points to. `char* pdest = s;` made pdest pointing at the same memory as `s`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

size_t undup (char *str);
size_t undup (char *str)
{
size_t src, dst;

for (src=dst=0; str[dst] = str[src++] ; ) {
  if (str[dst] != str[src] ) dst++;
  } 
return dst;
}

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{

  printf ("Before:%s\n", argv[1] );
  (void) undup ( argv[1] );
  printf ("After:%s\n", argv[1] );

  return 0;
}
```